# undefined method 'each for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a system that is currently in use and an error for a feature that is not very often used has come up.

```
NoMethodError in Offer_receipts#index

Showing /Users....../app/views/offer_receipts/index.html.erb where   line #8 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #8):

5:     <th>Patron</th>
6:     <th>One Time Offer</th>
7:   </tr>
8:   <% for offer_receipt in @offer_receipts %>
9:     <tr>
10:       <td><p> popld</p></td>
11:       <td><%= offer_receipt.patron_id %></td>
```

This error happens when this partial render page is currently being displayed:

```
<h2>Offers</h2>
<div id="offers">
<% if @offers.count > 0 %>
 < % @offers.each do |o| %>  
    <%= show_one_time_offer(o, @patron) %>
  <% end %>

<% else %>
  <strong>There are no offers currently available</strong>


<% end %>
</div>
```

Once the one time offer is clicked on, this page is loaded and this is the page the error happens on:

index.html.erb

```
<% title "Offer Receipts" %>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Patron</th>
    <th>One Time Offer</th>
  </tr>
  <% for offer_receipt in @offer_receipts %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= offer_receipt.patron_id %></td>
      <td><%= offer_receipt.one_time_offer_id %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Show", offer_receipt %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_offer_receipt_path(offer_receipt) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Destroy", offer_receipt, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<p><%= link_to "New Offer Receipt", new_offer_receipt_path %></p>
```

and here are two other files that define the methods and scope of the One Time Offer receipt

offer_receipt.rb

```
class OfferReceipt < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patron
  belongs_to :one_time_offer
  validates :patron, :presence=>true
  validates :one_time_offer, :presence=>true
  require 'offer_receipt_validator.rb'
  validates_with OfferReceiptValidator


end
```

offer_receipts_controller.rb

```
class OfferReceiptsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    begin
      @patron = Patron.find(params[:patron])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      flash[:error] = "You must provide a patron for an offer receipt"
      redirect_to root_url
      return
    end
    @offer_receipt = OfferReceipt.new(:patron_id=>params[:patron], :one_time_offer_id=>params[:one_time_offer])
    if @offer_receipt.save && @patron
      redirect_to @patron, :notice => "Recorded offer receipt"
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was a problem saving your offer receipt"
      redirect_to @patron
    end
  end
end
```

There are other index.html.erb files for listing other things with the exact same for each loop, and they are working fine. I also checked the database and there are over 2000 rows so that can't be the issue.

Comment: I don't see an index action in your OfferReceiptsController, that could be the issue.

Comment: In your `OfferReceiptsController`, could you show the `index` action? It looks like that `@offer_receipts` instance variable is nil. Maybe you're not setting it?

Answer (score 0):

Your instance variable, `@offer_receipt` is not set in your `#index` controller action.

You should add the `#index` action.  Something like this should work:

```
class OfferReceiptsController < ApplicationController 
  def index
    @offer_receipts = OfferReceipt.all
  end
end
```

You can also add additional logic in the `#index` action.  You might want to scope the instance variable to a `current_user`, for example.

```
@offer_receipts = OfferReceipt.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
```